# Dynamic footer content CodeIgniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have a newsletter signup in my view. I want this signup box and link to be visible only if

a) the user is not logged in

b) the user is logged in and has not subscribed yet

My view code looks like this:

```html
        <div id="footer">
            <div class="bottom clearfix">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-4 sitemap clearfix">
                            <h4>Hulp nodig?</h4>
                            <a href="#">Wat is</a>
                            <a href="#">Veelgestelde vragen</a>
                            <a href="#">Hoe werkt het?</a>
                            <a href="#">Contacteer ons</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 follow clearfix">
                            <h4>Follow us at</h4>
                            <a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank" class="facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                            <a href="" target="_blank" class="twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                            <a href="https://www.youtube.com" target="_blank" class="youtube"><i class="fa fa-youtube-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 newsletter clearfix">
                            <h4>Subscribe to newsletter</h4>
                            <p>
                                <input type="text" id="mail" placeholder="Mail" />
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-newsletter">Send</a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Now we have several controller files (Login, Register, User, Dashboard, Home, ...) which all have methods like this:

```html
public function index()
    {
        $this->is_logged_in();

        // Passing Variables
        $data['title'] = '';
        $data['class'] = 'home';

        // Template declaration
        $partials = array('head' => '_master/header/head_home', 'navigation' => '_master/header/navigation', 'banner' => 'home/home_banner', 'filter' => 'home/home_filter', 'features' => 'home/home_features', 'content' => 'home/home_content', 'footer' => '_master/footer/footer');
        $this->template->load('_master/master', $partials, $data);
    }
```

What I need is to call my own self defined methods which check in my database if the user has subscribed to the newsletter already or not. And based on that boolean result show the input field or not.

How do I deal with this problem the best possible way?

Answer (score 0):

There would be several ways, even I don't know the best way, but I'll give you a solution.

I think the best way and the easiest way to do this is by using sessions.

Inside you login functions/scripts, set an extra parameter to check subscription as same as user login status. according to this "$this->is_logged_in();" I hope you already have a parameter to check the login status.

I assume you're using codeigniter native libraries, if you're not, please do it as that external 3rd party way or your own way.

### in your login scripts,

```
// db script goes here for checking the user has been subscribed or not.
// according to the subscription status, the variable $subscription_status could be 0 or 1 (or wahtever you want)
// subscribed = 1, not = 0

$this->session->set_userdata('subscription' => $subscription_status);
```

### in your css,

```
.display_none
{
    display: none;
}
```

### in your view,

```
<div id="footer">
    <div class="bottom clearfix">
        <div class="container">

            <div id="subscription_box" class="row <?php echo empty($this->session->userdata('subscription_status')) || $this->session->userdata('subscription_status') !== 1? '' : 'display_none' ?>">
                <div class="col-lg-4 sitemap clearfix">
                    <h4>Hulp nodig?</h4>
                    <a href="#">Wat is</a>
                    <a href="#">Veelgestelde vragen</a>
                    <a href="#">Hoe werkt het?</a>
                    <a href="#">Contacteer ons</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 follow clearfix">
                    <h4>Follow us at</h4>
                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank" class="facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    <a href="" target="_blank" class="twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    <a href="https://www.youtube.com" target="_blank" class="youtube"><i class="fa fa-youtube-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 newsletter clearfix">
                    <h4>Subscribe to newsletter</h4>
                    <p>
                        <input type="text" id="mail" placeholder="Mail" />
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-newsletter">Send</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>  

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I put an id called "subscription_box" because if the user was subscribed, then you can remove the class 'display_none' from JavaScript by using AJAX. or any effect you want.

follow this to solve your problem in a better way,
[CodeIgniter Session Library](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html)